# What Happens when PWM Period register and Compare register is also loaded with same value

Tags: microcontroller, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, timer, duty-cycle

Consider, PWM engine based on timers,
PWM period register is loaded with 0x3FF (10bit, specifies the period of pwm frequency) and compare register( to vary the duty cycle , when timer count = cmp register toggle will happen in PWM line) is loaded with 0x3FF (100% duty cycle)same as period register, at these values does toggle will happens!? I captured in CRO there is no toggle there is no falling edge,only steady high line . my question is how micro controller will handle this case! When we configure compare register for 100% duty cycle!?does toggle happens or not.?
Thank you

Comment: That would most likely depend on which microcontroller this is about and what does the manual say how it works.

Comment: Closing as too broad - this depends on the device, and will be specified in the device's datasheet / programming manual. So, there's really nothing we can answer, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Consider atmeltiny1616 or any other microcontroller ! Generally what will happen!?